# count # of repeated words in a text file using java

Tags: java

how do you open a text file in java from a path and count the number of words repeated in the file using tokenizers.

Eg: want to open a file using the path name and being about to read and count the repeated words in the file

Comment: Your question is too open-ended.  It is unlikely that somebody will actually write the whole thing for you here; did you try doing it and something didn't work?  Did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1):

badpanda is half-right: there is lots of info already out there on how to read words from a file.  Don't take his suggestion of using ArrayLists though - all you need is one of the Map implementations (HashMap or TreeMap).  Each key is a word in the file, each value is the current count of that word.

Comment: My first instinct was the HashMap implementation (since it is essentially a more efficient version of the implementation I described below), but I thought perhaps it might be easier logically if ArrayLists were used instead (he is asking for help with streaming a file, after all...). When I was learning I felt skittish using data structures I did not understand, so I wouldn't want to suggest something to someone that would cause them to react similarly.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is homework, here are a few hints:

1. The `Scanner` class can be used as a tokenizer
2. A `Multiset` (or `Bag`) can be used to count words

And a little bit of detail about the approach which can be taken.

**Scanner as a tokenizer**

The [`Scanner`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class takes a source, such as a `InputStream` or `File` and can read data a piece at a time, using one of the many `next` methods which are available.

If we want to use the `Scanner` as a tokenizer, we could tell it the way it should split up the text in order to make the tokens.

There is a [`Scanner.useDelimiter(String)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter%28java.lang.String%29) or [`Scanner.useDelimiter(Pattern)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter%28java.util.regex.Pattern%29) method which can tell the `Scanner` to split tokens up in a certain way by using [regular expressions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Once the `Scanner` is properly configured, one can obtain tokens by calling the [`next`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) method until we run out of text in the text file. (The terminating condition of this loop could be determined by [`Scanner.hasNext`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext%28%29).)

**Using a `Multiset` (or `Bag`) to count words**

A data structure called a [*multiset*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) (or *bag*) can be used to keep track of words (or tokens) which may have occurred.

A multiset is a [set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29), but can have multiple elements for each of the element. In implementations I've seen, the element in the set will have its multiplicity available by calling some method.

For example, using the [`Multiset`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) implementation available in [Google's Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library, the [`Multiset.count(Object)`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html#count%28java.lang.Object%29) method will return the multiplicity of the given object.

So what does this all mean?

We could use a `Multiset` to keep track of the count of tokens that appear in the text file read by the `Scanner`.

By placing the tokens from the `Scanner` into the `Multiset`, we could end up with a count of the number of times each token has been encountered in the text file.

From there, we could iterate over the tokens, and find the tokens which have a count of over `2`, which are the tokens which were repeated in the text file.

**An alternate approach?**

Here's an alternative, from an alternative interpretation of the question:

> ... and count the number of words repeated in the file ...

If all we need is strictly a "count of repeated words", then there is an alternative approach.

A [`Set`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) could be used to keep track of tokens which have already been encountered in the file.

On each new token, before we attempt to `add` the token into the `Set`, we could check if the token already exists by using the [`Set.contains(Object)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) method.

If the word already exists, then we can increment a counter which keeps track of repeated tokens.

If this was not the intention of the question, then it should be mentioned that using precise wording to communicate intent is important, as people who read the question can interpret the question in many different ways! ;)

Comment: Hm ... I thought of using a `Dictionary<string,int>`. It seems less verbose to use it. Is Multiset more efficient? Where can I read up more on this?

Comment: @Hamish Grubijan: The multiset will keep track of the multiplicity of the elements. Using a `dictionary<string, int>` would mean that you'd have to keep track of the multiplicity with code you write. Using pre-written, pre-tested code is favorable in many circumstances. (Of course, it would be a good thing to do for educational purposes!)

Answer (score 0):

Find out how to stream a file from a path by googling it (below is the first link I found; if it is not good there are lots more...).

http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/read_a_textfile_in_java.html

Then, create an arraylist of arraylists. Add one entry (i.e. a new arraylist with the 0 index set to the word) to the initial arraylist for each new word, and add an entry to the corresponding arraylist for each repeated word. Once this is complete for the entire text document, iterate through the arraylist as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Forget tokenizers

Just use the String.split method.  It splits a string into a String array, and negates the need for the tokenizer class.

Use a Scanner to read in individual lines from the file.

Use a hash table to count the individual words, this is assuming that extra punctuation on words doesn't matter.

When the Scanner is done reading the file, display each key/value pair where the value is greater than 1.